# WebSQL database size difference on device (ios/Android) and on desktop

Tags: javascript, ios, html, sqlite, cordova

I am currently developping an HTML5/Jquery mobile application with Phonegap to embed it on devices (ios/Android).

This application requires an offline database and, on safari mobile, the size of this database cannot exceed 50MB. Which seems fine because when I check the filesize of the database on chrome on my win 7 desktop, the database is 37Mo.

This database is filled via a webservice in the application. When I try to do it from the desktop, no problem and the result file is 37Mo. However when I do it from a device (ios or android) the 50MB size limit is exceeded and the application throw an error.

Does someone know why the size of the file is different (actually, nearly twice) between the embedded database file and the desktop database file ?

And, moreover, how can I solve this ? (ie: how can I have an embedded file size smaller than 50MB ?).

Thanks for any input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure but just an idea. WebSQL use UTF-16 to store information but maybe in Chrome, it uses UTF-8.
See:

- [Determining HTML5 database memory usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3899983/determining-html5-database-memory-usage)
- http://hacks.mozilla.org/2012/03/people-of-html5-andrew-betts-on-building-the-ft-com-html5-app/

That might be why it's exactly twice

Comment: That seems to be it ! Thanks mate, now I will try to find a solution for this.