# SQLite. Cordova. Can't insert more than 995 rows

Tags: javascript, ios, angularjs, sqlite, cordova

I'm using:

- iPhone 5S, iOS 8.1.3
- or any iOS Simulator
- Cordova 4.0.0, Ionic v1.0.0-beta.14
- [Cordova/PhoneGap SQLitePlugin](https://github.com/brodysoft/Cordova-SQLitePlugin)

I use SQLite plugin with Angular wrapper. Function `self.insert()` inserts a row in table "stores". Function `self.query()` handles all queries and possible errors.
Function `$scope.init()` in controller is used to insert 20000 rows in table "stores".

**The problem:** 
Only first 996 rows are inserted. No errors. Sometimes 995 or 997 rows.

**Note:** 
Everything works in WebSQL (Chrome). All 20000 rows are inserted.

Thank you in advance!

Factory 1:

```
self.query = function(query, parameters) {
    return $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, query, parameters).then(function(result) {
       //console.log(result);
        return result;
    }, function (error) {
        console.log(error);
        return error;
    });
};
```

Factory 2:

```
self.insert = function(shop) {
    var parameters = [shop.storeId, shop.storeName, shop.address, shop.post, shop.city, shop.lat, shop.lng, shop.open, shop.favorites];
    return DB.query("INSERT INTO stores (storeId, storeName, address, post, city, lat, lng, open, favorites) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)", parameters);
};
```

Code in controller:

```
    $scope.init = function(){
        DB.query("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS stores");
        DB.query("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS stores (storeId integer,storeName text, address text, post text, city text, lat integer, lng integer, open text, favorites integer)");
        json_service.getJson().then(function(data){
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
                for (var j = 0; j < data[i].data.shops.length; j++) {
                    var coordinates = data[i].data.shops[j].g.split(",");
                    var oneStore = {
                        storeId: i + 1, 
                        storeName: data[i].data.title,
                        address: data[i].data.shops[j].a,
                        post: data[i].data.shops[j].p,
                        city: data[i].data.shops[j].s,
                        lat: coordinates[0],
                        lng: coordinates[1],
                        open: data[i].data.shops[j].t[0],
                        favorites: 0
                    };
                    stores_service.insert(oneStore);
                }
            }
        });
    };
```

Comment: What size are you setting for your DB? Seems like you are hitting a quota cap right around 995 records but sometimes get a bit more or less because the size of each record varies between each test.

[Determining HTML5 database memory usage](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3899983/determining-html5-database-memory-usage)

Comment: I'm using SQLite database, not HTML5.

Comment: Ahh right. I am in the process of looking into SQLite and researching it. I am bluring the lines I guess between the two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like [Cordova-sqlite-storage bug #190](https://github.com/litehelpers/Cordova-sqlite-storage/issues/190), which was observed on older versions of cordova-ios already solved on Cordova-iOS 3.8.0.